# How to grab a word from an array using its index-number (inside foreach)

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Example Name - Step 1
    [1] => Example Name - Step 1
    [2] => Example Name - Step 2
    [3] => Example Name - Step 3
    [4] => Example Name - Step 4
    [5] => Example Name - Step 4
)
```

as this is dynamically generated it can vary. But it always looks like this: `Example Name - Step X`
What I am trying to accomplish is to grab the previous key at every step inside a `foreach` loop.

I am then trying to compare the last name that was generated inside the foreach loop with the current name. I would use the `[1]`, `[3]` etc. but I cant find a documentation on [php.net](https://php.net) how to grab the previous and current index name. I would compare it using `if ($title == $title_array) {` but I am not able to find out how to make the `$title_array` get working. Since PHP 7.0 it is not possible to use [prev()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.prev.php) and therefor almost all links on SO are not working anymore.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far ?

Comment: @Nicolas I tried to grab the numbers after the "-" and then try to compare it, but it is not possible to do this inside a foreach. I also tried the prev but it doesnt work anymore in a foreach. I cant remember everything what I did in the last 7h trying to get this to work. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a foreach loop in php, there are 2 options:

```
foreach(array as element){}
```

and

```
foreach(array as index => element){}
```

If you use the latter, index will contain the index of the current element. From that you just need to access

```
$array[$index-1] //(as long as you are not at the 0th element.
```

So, your foreach would resemble:

```
$arr = Array
( 
    [0] => "Example Name - Step 1",
    [1] => "Example Name - Step 1",
    [2] => "Example Name - Step 2",
    [3] => "Example Name - Step 3",
    [4] => "Example Name - Step 4",
    [5] => "Example Name - Step 4"
)

foreach($arr as $i => $el){
    $prev_i = $i;
    if($i > 0)
        $prev_i = $i-1;
    // Now do whatever you want with the current ($arr[$i]) and previous($arr[$prev_i]) elements.
}
```

For more information on using foreach loops, read here: [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Why not put the `$prev_i` check into a ternary? E.g. `$prev_i = $i === 0 ? $i : $i-1;`

Comment: Thanks for this code, it works but it shows the loops before. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it shows the loops before". If you post your updated code, and output, we can probably offer more help.

Comment: @symlink - in actual code a ternary is the way to go. I always expand to an if (...) when trying to relay meaning just to make clarity easier

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if he does what you need. Try it.
For example, I create an array.

```
$example = ['Example Name_a','Example Name_1','Example Name_2','Example Name_3',
            'Example Name_3', 'Example Name_5', 'Example Name_7'];
```

At your request we will use a foreach loop.
To read the array index value one value smaller, create a counter.:

```
$ind = 0;

foreach($example as $k => $value):
   if($k != 0) {
     if($example[$k] === $example[$ind] {
        echo $example[$k] . " AND " . $example[$ind] . " TRUE " . "<br>"; $ind++; 
     } else {
        echo $example[$k] . " AND " . $example[$ind] . " NOT TRUE " . "<br>"; $ind++;     
     }
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop and compare each element against the previous one and enter them into a new array. Then call `array_unique()` to remove duplicates:

```
$arr = [
   "Example Name - Step 1",
   "Example Name - Step 1",
   "Example Name - Step 2",
   "Example Name - Step 3",
   "Example Name - Step 4",
   "Example Name - Step 4"
];
$matches = [];
for($i=1; $i<=count($arr); $i++){
   if($arr[$i-1] === $arr[$i]){
      $matches[] = $arr[$i];
   }
}

$matches = array_unique($matches);
```